# Запросы к API notion

Tags: python, api

Хочу получить страничку из notion через запрос к их api. Пишу на Python.
Вот такой код.

```
import requests
token = 'мой token_v2'

header = {'Autohorization': 'Bearer' + token, 'Notion-Version': '2021-05-13'}
req = requests.get('https://www.notion.so/2b79e5433b054ef0baab478dcf7c0295'
                   , headers=header)

print(req)
```

При выполнении выдает 401 ошибку авторизации. Токен беру из кэша (token_v2).
Возможно мой косяк в том, что я беру не тот токен. Возможно беру не тот id'шник страницы.
Может быть кто то встречался с такой проблемой?

Comment: а ещё `Autohorization` опечатка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в общем лучше использовать библиотеку notion-py. меньше мороки и проще забрать данные с notion.
https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py

мой пример, в принципе как в документации.

```
from notion.client import NotionClient
token = 'TokenV2'


client = NotionClient(token_v2=token)
page = client.get_block("Адрес вашей страницы")
print(page)
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в ответ ваш текущий код с использованием этой библиотеки :)

Comment: @gil9red добавил.

Comment: Спасибо :) Кст, не забудьте отметить ответ как решенный ;)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется у тебя нехватает пробела после `'Bearer'` и токен лепится прям кслову.